# How to test function returning Mono<Void> which has another Mono<T> within using Reactor's StepVerifier

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-reactor

I have a ServiceWebClientInterface.java like this

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public interface ServiceWebClientInterface {

    Mono<String> apiCall();
}
```

MyClass.java

```
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.AbstractGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

public class MyClass extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<MyClass.Config> {

    private final ServiceWebClientInterface serviceWebClientInterface;

    MyClass(final ServiceWebClientInterface serviceWebClientInterface) {
        this.serviceWebClientInterface = serviceWebClientInterface;
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            return serviceWebClientInterface.apiCall().flatMap(response -> {
                if (!"Valid".equals(response)) {
                    exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
                    return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
                }
                return chain.filter(exchange);
            });

        };
    }

    public static class Config  {
        // Put the configuration properties
    }
}
```

I'm trying to unit test myMethod using StepVerifier, but I am not able to execute statements inside the inner lambda function of myMethod.

MyClassTest.java

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilterChain;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
class MyClassTest {

    @Mock
    ServiceWebClientInterface mockServiceWebClientInterface;
    @Mock
    private ServerWebExchange mockServerWebExchange;
    @Mock
    private GatewayFilterChain mockGatewayFilterChain;
    @Mock
    private ServerHttpResponse mockServerHttpResponse;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void test_apply_forValid() {
        when(mockServiceWebClientInterface.apiCall()).thenReturn(Mono.just("Valid"));
        MyClass.Config config = new MyClass.Config();
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(mockServiceWebClientInterface);

        GatewayFilter gatewayFilter = myClass.apply(config);

        Mono<Void> response = gatewayFilter.filter(mockServerWebExchange, mockGatewayFilterChain);

        StepVerifier.create(response).expectComplete();

        verify(mockServiceWebClientInterface).apiCall();
        verify(mockGatewayFilterChain).filter(mockServerWebExchange);

    }

    @Test
    void test_apply_forInValid() {
        when(mockServiceWebClientInterface.apiCall()).thenReturn(Mono.just("InValid"));
        when(mockServerWebExchange.getResponse()).thenReturn(mockServerHttpResponse);
        MyClass.Config config = new MyClass.Config();
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(mockServiceWebClientInterface);

        GatewayFilter gatewayFilter = myClass.apply(config);

        Mono<Void> response = gatewayFilter.filter(mockServerWebExchange, mockGatewayFilterChain);

        StepVerifier.create(response).expectComplete();

        verify(mockServiceWebClientInterface).apiCall();
        verify(mockServerHttpResponse).setStatusCode(eq(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN));
        verify(mockServerHttpResponse).setComplete();
        verify(mockGatewayFilterChain, never()).filter(mockServerWebExchange);

    }


}
```

Please find the complete code above, When I run the tests I observe that the inner lambda function does not get invoked using the step verifier.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to test the class that implements `MyLambda` interface.
For sure you inject there `serviceWebClientInterface` as mentioned on code snippet.

To unit test that class, you should mock the `serviceWebClientInterface.apiCall()` and verify if it was called. As an addition to your actual code snippet.

You can use Mockito library for that purpose.

- create a mock:

`given(serviceWebClientInterface).willReturn(Mono.just("some text"));`

- then verify if it is called:

`verify(serviceWebClientInterface).apiCall()`

Comment: yes you are right. I inject serviceWebClientInterface and Mock as you have mentioned. But when I use `StepVerifier.create(resultMono).verifyComplete();` and verify using `verify(serviceWebClientInterface).apiCall()` I see it is not being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by using
StepVerifier.create(response).verifyComplete();

and mocking chain.filter(exchange);